# Every time I log into the Salesforce environment I get a welcome email

Tags: trigger, community, email, visual-workflow

I have a strange problem. Every time I log into my company's environment, I get a welcome email from Community.

It has two problems:

- My username is not from the community;
- Welcome email should not be sent to logins and should only be sent once.

Has anyone gone through this and have any ideas? I looked for some flow-trigger or apex-trigger that is causing this but I didn't find anything.